# Any guidelines to develop a Qt UI with Pyside?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm **new** to Qt and Pyside, and confused with lots of dazzling concepts and tools.

**Instead of using IDE provided, I prefer to vim.**

So I wonder what the generic guideline is. That is to say, what're the QML, Qt Creator, Qt Designer? Do I need to use all of them? And what's the normal workflow?

And at last, there're few tutorials about Qt in python, so can I invoke the Qt C++ docs for help (any big differences between C++ Qt programming and Python one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make GUIs in a text editor, right in the Python program. You don't have to use QML, Qt Creator. Just read the Jan Bodnar's [**PySide tutorial**](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/) and then you'll be able to figure out the rest by yourself, by looking at PySide or C++ Qt documentation

Answer (score 3):

I wrote some PyQt based tutorials after leaving my last job, they can apply to PySide also and have some helpful tips in there too: http://bitesofcode.blogspot.com/

I agree you don't need QML or Qt Creator - but using the Qt Designer for building your interfaces would definitely be the way I would recommend going about it.

Comment: Thank you~ Can you show me the very important concepts in QT? That would be great help.